# Interesting observation on infinite sequence of real roots of trigonometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I noticed a correlation between secant values and the roots of trigonometric equations, resulting in infinite sequences (Quite a mouthfull I know :)

Consider the equation $\sec(x)\tan(x)=\sqrt{2}$

The real roots of the equation are: $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi, \dfrac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi,$
resulting in the values $\dfrac{\pi}{4},\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\dfrac{-5\pi}{4},\dfrac{-7\pi}{4},\dfrac{11\pi}{4},\dfrac{13\pi}{4},\cdots$.

Now we know that the sum of the reciprocals of the roots of a polynomial:
$$
\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}}=-\dfrac{F'(0)}{F(0)}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Here
$$
\begin{split}
\dfrac{4}{\pi}+\dfrac{4}{3\pi}-\dfrac{4}{5\pi}-\dfrac{4}{7\pi}+\dfrac{4}{11\pi}+\dfrac{4}{13\pi} +\cdots&+\sum\dfrac{1}{\text{Imaginary Roots}}\\ 
& = \dfrac{-\sec\left(0\right)\tan^2\left(0\right)-\sec^3\left(0\right)}{\sec(0)\tan(0)-\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
Thus
$$\sum\dfrac{\pi}{4}{\dfrac{1}{\text{Real}_i}}+\sum\dfrac{\pi}{4}{\dfrac{1}{\text{Img}_i}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{4}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sum\dfrac{1}{\text{Imaginary Roots}}+\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\cdots\right).
$$
Now,
$$
\sum{\dfrac{1}{\text{Real}_i}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\cdots=\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
from: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html (10th formula)
$$
\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=(\sqrt2)^2\dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}=\left(\sec\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)^2\dfrac{\pi}{4\sqrt{2}}\implies\left({\sec\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}\right)^2\cdot{\dfrac{\pi/4}{\sqrt{2}}}
$$

Considering another equation, i.e. $\sec(x)\tan(x)=\dfrac{2}{3}$, the zeros are $x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}+2n\pi$, and repeat steps \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} we get
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum\dfrac{\pi}{6}{\dfrac{1}{\text{Real}_i}}+\sum\dfrac{\pi}{6}{\dfrac{1}{\text{Img}_i}}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\\
&\sum{\dfrac{1}{\text{Real}_i}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\dfrac{1}{17}+\cdots
\end{align}
$$
which is essentially the Leibniz $\pi$ formula with the addition of the term $\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{1}-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\cdots\right)$.
So
$$
\sum{\dfrac{1}{\text{Real}_i}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}+\dfrac{1}{17}+\cdots=\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi}{12}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}
$$
Notice again that
$$
\dfrac{\pi}{3}=\dfrac{2^2}{\sqrt{3}^2}\dfrac{\pi}{4}={\left(\sec\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)^2}\cdot\dfrac{\pi}{4}\implies\left({\sec\left(\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right)}\right)^2\cdot{\dfrac{\pi/6}{2/3}}.
$$

TL;DR

Consider in general $\sec(x)\tan(x)=k$.
Generally from observation it appears that
$$
\sec^2(x_\text{root})\cdot\dfrac{(\text{Smallest root})}{k}=\sum\dfrac{1}{\text{RealRoots}_i}=\dfrac{Smallest root}{\sin(x_{root})}, 
$$ where $k=\sec(x)\tan(x)$ gives infinite sequences of the reciprocals of its real roots. Consequently,
$$
-\tan^2(x_\text{root})\cdot\dfrac{(\text{Smallest root})}{k}=\sum\dfrac{1}{\text{ImgRoots}_i}={Smallest root}\cdot{\sin(x_{root})}
$$ gives infinite sequences of the reciprocals of its imaginary roots.

However, this is just observation. I know this is really messy but the infinite summations do seem to be equal to the values on the LHS: the reason is not clear. Moreover it is worth to point out that proving this result might also result in a generalization of Leibniz like formulae for $\pi$.

I would like to know if this has been observed before and if a proof for the observed relation exists.

Comment: No... $\sec(x)\tan(x)=\sqrt{2}$ implies $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\sqrt{2}$, x can take the values π/4+2πn or 3π/4+2πn. I think you accidentally applied the wrong identity ;(

Comment: You are right, my blindness.  I therefore deleted my comment.

Comment: A consequence of this generalization is this neat formula: $\dfrac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{8}-\dfrac{1}{10}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\cdots$ Has this summation been found before?

Comment: I can't find any references for this summation yet :). I wonder if this observed identity could also somehow be extended and generalized for other trigonometric functions and equations like $\sec^2(x)\tan(x)=k$ or something. So many interesting ways to denote $\pi$!!!

Comment: @Lithium That infinite series is equal to $L(1,\chi_{-6}) + \frac12L(1,\chi_{-3})$, where $L(1,\chi_{-6}) = \frac11-\frac15+\frac17-\frac1{11}+\cdots = \frac\pi{2\sqrt3}$ and $L(1,\chi_{-3}) = \frac11-\frac12+\frac14-\frac15+\cdots = \frac\pi{3\sqrt3}$ are special values of quadratic Dirichlet $L$-functions (dense reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula)).

Comment: Very interesting thank you:) I have almost zero knowledge in high level maths, I want to know if the discovered identity is novel or not :) If not then is the identity analogous to the Dirichlet L-function? Can the identity be proved using them?

Comment: Note, you are using "imaginary" when you mean "non-real complex." The imaginary numbers are the numbers of the form $bi$ where $b$ is real.

Comment: @GregMartin the information about the Dirichlet L-function is very vague and I can't figure out if what I observed is exactly the same as what Dirichlet proved. There aren't too many online resources that go into detail about the proof. I can definitely see the similarity on the Wikipedia page, however I might need to know if they are the same in order to prove the identity :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\sec z \tan z=k$ as $k\cos^2 z=\sin z$ and thus, using $\cos ^2z=1-\sin^2z,$ we have $$k\sin^2 z+\sin z-k=0.$$

This gives, at least when $k\neq 0,$

$$\sin z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4k^2}}{2k}.$$

When $k$ is real, this gives $y=\sin z$ real.

In that case, if $|y|\leq 1,$ you can show that the value of $w$ must be on the unit circle, and hence $z$ must be real.

If $|y|>1,$ then $\cos z=\pm i\sqrt{y^2-1}$ and $w=i(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-1})$ is purely imaginary.

So the only roots are $z$ real and $\operatorname{Re} z=\frac{\pi}2+\pi m$ for some integer $m.$

If $k=\sqrt2,$ then $y=\frac1{\sqrt2},$ or $-\sqrt2.$

In the latter case, $\cos z=\pm i$ and $e^{iz}=(-\sqrt{2}\pm 1)i,$ or $z=-\frac\pi2+2\pi m\pm i\log(1+\sqrt2)$ for some integer $m.$

So the non-real roots are:

$$z=\frac{4m-1}{2}\pi \pm i\log(1+\sqrt2).$$

Comment: Ohh very nice work thank you :) So the logarithm values are also interlinked with $\pi$ and number sequences!!